# target parent node from child node using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have following structure.

```
<dl>
    <dt class="tab">..</dt>
    <dd class="tab-container">..</dd>
    <dt class="tab">
         <div class="hi">hello</div>
    </dt>
    <dd class="tab-container">...</dd>
    <dt class="tab">...</dt>
    <dd class="tab-container">...</dd>
</dl>
```

i want to add new class to last dd element when clicked on "hi" div .how can i achieve using jquery.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: stackoverflow is for solving problems with **existing** code and no *giv-me-the-codez* site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to learn traversing. answer to your question[asked in comments]

```
$(this).parents('dl').prev().closest('ul').children('li').eq(-2).addClass('new classs');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use as [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get relevant `dd` ancestor and then target last `dl`:

```
$('div.hi').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('dl').children('dd:last-child').addClass('myNewClass');
});
```

Comment: how to target second last dd ?

Comment: @user5962477 use `eq()` with negative index: `$(this).closest('dl').children('dd').eq(-2)`

Comment: thanks.one more question .how can i target other elements which are not under <dl> tag.

Comment: <ul>; ;; ; ; ; </ul> <dl>;;;;</dl> i want to target li elements of ul tag also.

Comment: You have to ask other question because otherwise in 10 years you will still ask new question$ in comments and still not show any effort to try to understand the code you are coping/pasting...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
$(".hi").click(function () {
    $(this).closest("dl").find("dd:last-child").addClass("blue");
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/z24toqL2/

Answer (score 1):

Hi there :) You can use parent() or parents() - [documentation for parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

So, try this:

```
$('.hi').on('click', function() {
   // In that case- parents('dl') - try to catch a dl parent
   $(this).parents('dl').find('dd:last-of-type').addClass('new-class');
});
```

You can  [view online here in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/UltraDev/yhkuprao/).

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use [`jQuery.parents`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) to traverse up the DOM tree until you find the `dl` element.

```
$('.hi').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parents('dl').find('dd:last').addClass('my-new-class');
});
```

Here's the jQuery [API documentation category](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) for DOM tree traversal - there's more than one way to do it.